# How to unit test functions that return random values in r package development?

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I have a function which rounds of decimals stochastically.

If I have a input like this:

`data = c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9)`

Using the function

```
round_stocho(data)
```

will return :

> 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2

again if i run,

```
round_stocho(data)
```

it will return

> 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2

> Im not allowed to share the function, as it is my office work, but I hope the viewers understand that I'm getting a random result every time.

For such functions, what tests (using testthat function) should be used ? Is it expect_snapshot ?

Comment: You can check that the return value is of the correct type and length. If the return value is expected to have certain properties (eg at least one one and at least one two), test those. Perhaps, with a fixed seed (or a “stub” rv generator, if you’re using a custom generator) you can predict exactly what the return value will be. Understand, with a generic question with no critical code to share, you’re likely to get generic advice.

Comment: `help("set.seed")`

Comment: @Roland: Whilst `set.seed()` is useful in basic scenarios, there are several situations in which it does not *guarantee* reproducibility: uprades to R (very annoying), change of operating system, use of packages that do not use R's standard RNGs (rjags comes to mind)...  That's why I believe stub generators are often more useful in testing.

Comment: @Limey:  upgrades to R may change the RNG if bugs are fixed, but the old version is always available in the new R.  OS changes should have no effect on R's RNGs.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.